# Sql Query Grouping and select Complete Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to write a query to select the id of employee who joined the department first for this I apply grouping on deptId and Min aggregate function on join date.

```
EmpId joinDate  deptId
1      2/5/2012   2
2      5/6/2012   1
3      2/5/2012   2
4      5/58/2012  2
```

My result should be:

```
EmpId joinDate  deptId
1      2/5/2012   2
2      5/6/2012   1
```

I am unable to get EmpId, my EmpId is of type Guid.  Is there any possible solution for that.  I am using MS SQL SERVER 2008.

Comment: EmpId is not GUID..... r u sure its GUID....?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer - EMP_Id is assigned `Guid` values and is actually a `String` type or it is a `GUID` type ?

Comment: in my example above it is not GUID but in actual Db it is GUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this query and let me know

```
select EmpId, joinDate , deptId from
(select row_number() over(partition by deptId order by joinDate) as rnk,*
from employe)E
where E.rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit simpler solution:

```
SELECT * FROM employees a WHERE joinDate IN
(SELECT MAX(b.joinDate) FROM employees b WHERE b.deptId = a.deptId)
```

assuming that your table's name is `employees` and that you want to get all employees from the department who joined first (there can be more than one!).
Disclaimer: not tested on MS SQL Server but on PostgreSQL, however it's a simple SQL and I think it should work.